# If $f(r)$ be the integer closest to $\sqrt[4]{r}$, then calculate the value of $\sum^{1995}_{r=1} \frac{1}{f(r)}$

Tags: summation

> If $f(r)$ be the integer closest to $\sqrt[4]{r}$, then what is the value of $\displaystyle\sum^{1995}_{r=1} \frac{1}{f(r)}$ ?

I am thinking like this way , if we have a number $>1.5$, then its closest integer is $2,$ but I did not understand how to solve  that question.

Could some help me to solve it, thanks.

Comment: there is no equation... actually there is no question.

Comment: I think he means find the sum..

Comment: What is the source of the problem, and why is it of mathematical interest ? The unmotivated number '1995' suggests this might just be some kind of contest problem.  Why was that number chosen rather than any other?

Answer (score 2):

This PARI/GP command calculates the value :

```
? sum(j=1,1995,1/round(j^(1/4)))
%1 = 400
?
```

Comment: You lazy boy. One can do it by hand ; to see why, try `vector(1995,j,1/round(j^(1/4)))` in GP and you'll see

Comment: True, on the other hand, the author did not react to the question whether he/she wants a solution by hand ...

Comment: Indeed. I hate those posts where the author is unresponsive ... Hopefully he'll react soon

Comment: The main effort is to find the exact bounds for the numbers falling into the different classes given by $f(n)=c$

Comment: For the relatively small number 1995, this is  doable by hand, even if tedious. I agree that one should not make that effort for an asker who isn't even minimally responsive

Comment: Well, should I add a hint to encourage the author to solve it him/herself ?

Comment: It's already all there in the comments we just made here, I think ...

Answer (score 2):

A hint:  Use your pocket calculator to produce a table of the values $1.5^4$, $2.5^4$, $\ldots$, $7.5^4$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* 
$f$ is a piecewise constant function with jumps from $n$ to $n+1$ at $\lceil (n+0.5)^4\rceil$. You just need to find how long the intervals are in $[1,1995]$.

> Surprisingly, the sum is an integer. More surprisingly, each combined term is an integer: $$\sum^{1995}_{r=1} \frac{1}{f(r)} = \frac{5}{1}+\frac{34}{2}+\frac{111}{3}+\frac{260}{4}+\frac{505}{5}+\frac{870}{6}+\frac{210}{7} = 400$$